# JQGrid with Column Reordering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid and I can reorder my columns with this option in my JQGrid

```
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                sortable: true,
                ... 
});
```

This functionality let me reorder ALL my columns. But I want that some columns must be on fixed places. Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Bruno

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never say never. jqGrid uses jQueryUI's Sortable class to perform the column drag-n-drop function. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

To remove a column from the list of sortable columns, run these two commands after you've rendered your grid (with sortable: true).

```js
// disable the sortable property on your target element 
// (which was applied when jqGrid rendered the grid)
$('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').sortable({ cancel: 'th:#element_id'});
// update the list of sortable item's, and exclude your target element
$('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').sortable({ items: "th:not(#element_id)" });
```

**Note:** This works best if your unsortable columns are on the left or right edge of the grid. Otherwise, you will still be able to re-sort other columns around them.

**Also:** Make sure you understand the difference between the two sortable options (grid level and colmodel level). On the grid options, "sortable: true" means the columns can be reorders by drag-and-drop. On the colmodel options, "sortable: true" means that you can reorder the rows by clicking on the column's header. Setting sortable to true on the grid options will not cascade down to the colmodel options. However, on the colmodel sortable is true by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i have to update this project i'll check it out! :)

Comment: You should at least accept Walters' comment in the mean time.  It's better then "It's impossible".

Comment: Can multiple th ids can be applied to the code above for fixing the order for multiple columns ?

Comment: @Sandy505 : probably, you'll have to test for yourself. Refer to http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-cancel . The parameter you pass into cancel/items is just selector, so you just need to write a selector that will select all the th's that you want to modify.

My guess is the syntax would be something like 
$('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels').sortable({ cancel: 'th:#element_id, th:#element_id2,th:#element_id3'});

Comment: @TomHalladay I think you meant to say "accept _Walter's_ comment" since there is only one of me.

Answer (score 3):

Now in 2013 you can define the "exclude" parameter of "sortable"
, like this :

```
sortable: {
    exclude: '#'+ grid[0].id +'_actions_buttons'
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `sortable` for each column in the `colModel`

```
colModel: [{ name: 'name', index: 'name', sortable: true },...
```

Checkout the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:colmodel_options) it's pretty helpful.

Comment: if you enable that option, you can sort the table on that column.
This will not affect my column to reorder the column from position.
It would be nice if there was an option that i can put in my colmodel to disable the reordering for just one column...
But thx.

Comment: doesn't look like this is possible with the jqgrid settings, you could try catch the th click event an stop the ordering for certain columns

Answer (score 1):

This ain't possible in jqgrid. I searched also a long time for this. And everything i tried failed.