# jqGrid - Disable Reordering of Specific Columns

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with the grid-level 'sortable' option enabled. This lets me drag columns around to reorder them, which is great. But I want to prevent users from doing this with one specific column, leaving the others unaffected. Is this possible?

Comment: Oh, I think I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317199/jqgrid-with-column-reordering

Answer (score 0):

I find your question very interesting and so I made [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/sortablecolumns2.htm) which demonstrate the solution. On the demo is the first column "Date" unsortable.

I recommend you to read two other old answers on the close subject: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775577/315935) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9045125/315935). My suggesting are based on the same idea.

There are internal jqGrid method [sortableColumns](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.jqueryui.js#L52) which will be used internally if one uses `sortable: true` option of jqGrid. The `sortableColumns` method uses jQuery Sortable for the implementation and initializes `items` options of the grid having `id="list"` to the value ">th:not(:has(#jqgh_list_cb,#jqgh_list_rn,#jqgh_list_subgrid),:hidden)". It makes the columns `"cb"`, `"rn"` and `"subgrid"` unsortable. The columns could be inserted in the grid if you use jqGrid options `multiselect: true`, `rownumbers: true` or `subGrid: true`. In the same way is you have the column with `name: "invdate"` then the corresponding id of the column element will be `jqgh_list_invdate`. So one can use the option `sortable` as the following

```js
sortable: {
    options: {
        items: ">th:not(:has(#jqgh_list_cb,#jqgh_list_invdate,#jqgh_list_rn,#jqgh_list_subgrid),:hidden)"
    }
}
```

to make the `"invdate"` column unsortable.