# Should the colNames and colModel be updated on the DOM on column sort in jQgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I am having a weird issue and I haven't a clue in how to fix this.

Let's say I have a grid which is build on the server side - yes, we've a class `DynamicGrid` (PHP) receiving a few parameters and building all the HTML/JS needed by jQgrid to render a grid.

We're also storing the grid setup in a MongoDB as for example: columns sort (horizontal & vertical) and some other custom stuff.

When the grid loads for first time the data is displayed properly. [This is](https://gist.github.com/reypm/608dc90efeb2cec190a82d2a7fcbeccb) how the code looks like after being generated (example on Gists since it's a big one).

[image]

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/reypm/9924ec2f4ee6391ba150f68bbce1bdfe) a JSON data passed to the grid.

I can even sort the columns and it still working (column AgreementId has been reordered):

[image]

Each time I paginate the grid I check for the stored settings looking for any change (in fact it's returning all the time what's stored so no checking on differences at all) the proper order on the `colNames` and `colModel`.

I can say (and can leave an example if needed) the `colNames` and `colModel` are coming as sorted previously. The JSON data is coming properly ordered as well.

For some reason the grid is misaligned and the values won't display properly anymore.

[image]

Check in the image above how the `AgreementId` and the `Quote Status` are misaligned as what I have on the 2nd image.

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/reypm/fde19bb0a7f53ae605373eb2d8912212) the data returned on the pagination. The order looks fine to me so there is nothing wrong on the backend part seems to be a Javascript + DOM issue or I don't know because this is killing me.

Can any give me some ideas in how to deal with this or fix it at all? The version of jQgrid used is free-jqGrid 4.14.1.

**UPDATE:** <strike>I think the problem could be maybe on the column "Actions" how do I fix this column to be the first one all the time and do not allow to sort it?</strike>

I have managed to move the values for the column `Actions` at the beginning of my JSON data but that doesn't fix the issue.

For some reason as soon as I move forward/backward the model is not being updated properly in the DOM or somewhere and the wrong data is show at the wrong column.

I am currently out of ideas so any help still welcome :)

Comment: Trying to understand. The data only gets into the wrong cells when you page the grid? Can you show a "working" data return from the server and  a "non-working" return?

Comment: @gforce301 I have added more info on the OP also the JSON as you requested ...

Comment: @gforce301 you mean like [this](https://gist.github.com/reypm/608dc90efeb2cec190a82d2a7fcbeccb#file-default1-json) ?? somehow I can sort the column no matter what

Comment: My mistake. That only disables "sorting" of the data in the coiumn. Read this for an answer of making certain columns unable to be "reordered". [jqGrid - Disable Reordering of Specific Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607931/jqgrid-disable-reordering-of-specific-columns)

Comment: This post [JQGrid with Column Reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317199/jqgrid-with-column-reordering) gives another method of stopping a column from being reordered.

Comment: @gforce301 thx but that's not the issue currently I've tried to explain it as best as I could